# Nginx Reverse Proxy for node server returning 404 for css/js files

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm trying to setup a node server for wiki.js with a NGINX reverse proxy. I followed the wiki.js installation instructions and have the files extracted into `/var/www/site/main/wiki` so the file structure looks as follows:

```
var
  - www
    - site
      - main
        - wiki
          -assets  
          -config.yml  
          -LICENSE  
          -node_modules  
          -package.json  
          -server
```

I can run the `node server` command in that directory and it instructed me to continue the setup by going to `http://localhost:3000`. I then tried to visit the site by it's domain, and the page title is being set to `wiki.js Setup` so something is passing through the Nginx proxy, but all css/js files are returning a 404 error causing the page to fail to render.

I used a setup from https://nginxconfig.io to configure the Nginx proxy, and the server block is as follows:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name example.com;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

        # security
        include nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

        # reverse proxy
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

                # This next block is actually include with a include 
                # nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf call but this is the contents of that file

                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade                        $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection             "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host                           $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP                      $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $server_port;
        }

        # additional config
        include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}

# subdomains redirect
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name *.example.com;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name .example.com;

        include nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

        location / {
                return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself. After poking and prodding, I found there are multiple issues with the nginxconfig.io setup; it seems to want to configure *too many things* and this gets in the way of wiki.js actually being able to do its own thing.

- Content-Security-Policy needs to be unset
- Removed all includes in an effort to debug faster

As of right now (2020-05-16_14-11) these are valid working server blocks:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name wiki.domain.invalid;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wiki.domain.invalid/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wiki.domain.invalid/privkey.pem; #managed by Certbot
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wiki.domain.invalid/chain.pem;

    # security headers
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0" always;

    # . files
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
        deny all;
    }

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/wiki.domain.invalid.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wiki.domain.invalid.error.log warn;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version                  1.1;
        #proxy_cache_bypass                  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection         "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
                proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }

    # gzip
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
}

    # HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name wiki.domain.invalid;

    # ACME-challenge
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/_letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://wiki.domain.invalid$request_uri;
    }

 }
```